# How to plot a graph with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Good evening, I am a student taking a required python course (completely new to coding) in Hong Kong.

I was asked to write a python program that shows a graph in an assignment, but I had encountered some difficulties.

I tried to follow some source codes I found on the internet, but it end up showing a bug-like page.

Can someone please kindly tell me which part of my code is wrong, how to correct it, and why is this resulting happening?

Also, I would like to ask that is there any difference between import as mpl and as plt?

source code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl 
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

xaxis = np.array([2,8])
yaxis = np.array([4,9])

plt.plot(xaxis, yaxis )
plt.show()

plt.savefig('table.png')
```

result:
[bug-like result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJUKE.png)

Thank you all very much. Hope you have a nice day.

Comment: You can open in image ONLY in a software able to intepret it. The website you use, just shows you the bytes in the file, and you can't display the image neither regarding the warning in the console. Execute the program locally on your laptop OR download the file `table.png` and open it on your laptop

Comment: I just changed my platform into PyCharm and removed the first two lines of my code, and obtained the result. Thank you very much.

Comment: altough the question you posted is not really about python (as you realized) I think the question was clear and easy to understand. the problem was a single isolated one. a nice first question. :)